# Error in method Unable to evaluate expression

Tags: c#, mysql

Im getting this error,

> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

And I don't know what is causing it.

There are two methods Login and Session Selection. The login session just matches email and a password; and the session selection queries the db with a GUID that will be used as the session ID. The error is thrown when I call `SessionSelection()` in Login

```
private void SessionSelection( )
{


 string connectstr = "data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True; Initial Catalog= NewApp";

    try
    {
        string query = @"SELECT UserIDkey FROM Registration WHERE Email='" + txtEmail.Text.Trim() + "'";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectstr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string SessionResult = reader["UserIDkey"].ToString();
            Session["PrivateKey"] = SessionResult;

            //SessionResult = SpecialKey;
        }
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
    }

}


private void Login()
{

    string passwordEncryption = txtPassword.Text.Trim();

    System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider x2 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] bs2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwordEncryption);
    bs2 = x2.ComputeHash(bs2);
    System.Text.StringBuilder s2 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in bs2)
    {
        s2.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
    }
    string EncryptedPassword = s2.ToString();


    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmail.Text))
    {
        string connectstr = "data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True; Initial Catalog= NewApp";
        //  (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"]); 
        try
        {
            string query = @"SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE Email='" + txtEmail.Text.Trim() + "'and Password='" + EncryptedPassword + "'";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectstr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            con.Open();

            var Results = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            //string sqlRead = cmd.ExecuteReader().ToString();

            if (Results > 0)
            {


                SessionSelection();

                txtEmail.Text = "";
                txtPassword.Text = "";
                Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
            }

            else
            {
                Response.Write("Incorrect UserName/Password");
            }
            con.Close();
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Incorrect UserName/Password");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What did you get when you googled your error message?

Comment: Where i call SessionSelection() in Login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** You are not giving space between your `Email string` and `and` keyword in your command string in `Login()` method:

```
string query = @"SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE Email= 
         '" + txtEmail.Text.Trim() + "'and Password='" + EncryptedPassword + "'";
                                      ^^^
```

**Solution :** You needto have space between your `Email string` and `and` keyword in your command string in `Login()` method:

Try This:

```
string query = @"SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE Email= 
      '" + txtEmail.Text.Trim() + "' and Password='" + EncryptedPassword + "'";
```

**Suggestion:** Your query is open to `SQL Injection attacks` so I'd strongly suggest you to use `Parameterised queries` to avoid `SQL Injection attacks`.

**Solution 2:** with  `Parameterised queries`

```
try
{
    string query = @"SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE Email=@Email 
                                                        and Password=@Password";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectstr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email",txtEmail.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password",EncryptedPassword);
    con.Open();
    var Results = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    //string sqlRead = cmd.ExecuteReader().ToString();
    if (Results > 0)
    {
        SessionSelection();
        txtEmail.Text = "";
        txtPassword.Text = "";
        Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Incorrect UserName/Password");
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was **Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx", false);**

To work around this problem, use one of the following methods:
For Response.End, call the HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest method instead of Response.End to bypass the code execution to the Application_EndRequest event.
For Response.Redirect, use an overload, Response.Redirect(String url, bool endResponse) that passes false for the endResponse parameter to suppress the internal call to Response.End. For example:
  Response.Redirect ("nextpage.aspx", false);

If you use this workaround, the code that follows Response.Redirect is executed.
For Server.Transfer, use the Server.Execute method instead.

**Fix**
Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx", false);